# css file not showing in chrome developer tool

Tags: css, wordpress

Trying to create a new wordpress theme, when I look for CSS file in the developer tools it doesn't appear, even if I have a file saved as style.css in the same theme folder . As you can imagine the website does not have any stile but the theme preview do display theme name and author (wrote as a comment in the CSS file). Thanks

Comment: Have you even linked the CSS file? Have you tried to clear cache?

Comment: Upload some screenshots

Comment: Did both, just typing bug. Thanks!

Comment: Naming function.php instead of functions.php the file resulted not linked